# How to change the partition which MBR points to?

Tags: grub

I can not boot my computer, so I use Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD instead.

I change the partition of boot loader from sda9 to sda8, so the MBR cannot point to the correct loader.

How could I do now? How to change the partition which MBR points to? Thanks.

Comment: Did you move you boot folder to another partition, and is it Ubuntu that is installed on your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. /dev/sda1 was mounted as /boot. I had created /dev/sda3 and copied everything from /dev/sda1 to /dev/sda3 and pointed/labelled (with fdisk) that /dev/sda3 is boot. Mounted /dev/sda3 to my system /boot folder (in /etc/fstab) but it still didn't help. When I deleted everything from /dev/sda1 the system didn't start.

So I copied from /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda1 (as sda3 was kind of backup) and run system normally. System think that /dev/sda3 which is /boot is really boot area. So I did (for fedora, for debian derivates there probably update-grub needed):

```
grub2-install /dev/sda
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

and grub repointed to /dev/sda3 and everything works fine now.